Check the current route in React inertia and access it in the Link tag
I want to access the current route for me to be able to dynamically change the tag colors.
<Link href={route('/')} className={($page ==='/about' ? 'text-blue' : 'text-green')}>Link</Link>

I tried library ziggy but not sure how to do it.
import { useRoute } from "../../../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy"
 const route = useRoute();

I tried console.log but it doesn't show anything useful. Maybe am missing something here.
thanks

Check you have correctly imported and set up Ziggy in your React component. Beacuse Ziggy provides a route() function.
Follow these examples:

Import the Hook:
import React from 'react';
import { InertiaLink, usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

Access the Current Route:
const { url } = usePage();

Conditionally Render Your Link Component
const isActive = (path) => url === path;
return (<InertiaLink href={route('home')} className={isActive('/about') ? 'text-blue' : 'text-green'} >Home);


